# Keras Logistic Regression returns nan on first epoch

Tags: python, theano, keras, logistic-regression

I have a really simple data set. I cleaned the data (one hot encoding, normalizing the data and check for missing values or NaNs) and my learning rate is pretty small. But when tried to run a simple logistic regression using Keras and Theano as backend

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(input_dim=84, activation='softmax',
            bias_initializer='normal', units=6)) 
rms = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=rms, loss='categorical_crossentropy')


batch_size = 100
nb_epoch = 1
n = X.shape[0] # number of training examples
history = model.fit(X, Y_oh, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch)
```

Error:

```
Epoch 1/1
5459/5459 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
```

I checked [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5377) and tried to downgrade Theano to the version mentioned but it still gives the same error

Here is what X looks like

```
[[ 0.35755179  0.13747887  0.3        ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.36401758  0.14963742  0.55       ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.37889517  0.13775149  0.275      ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.34387947  0.18706723  0.05       ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.35708726  0.12905512  0.75       ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.37915882  0.08061174  0.05       ...,  0.          1.          0.        ]]
```

and Y_oh (generated using the following code):

```
Y_oh = np_utils.to_categorical(Y.T[0],6)

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your activation here

```
model.add(Dense(input_dim=84, activation='softmax',
            bias_initializer='normal', units=6))
```

**Swap 'softmax' for 'sigmoid' (or 'tanh') and you should be good.**

**Softmax** has the property that the **sum of its outputs is 1**, so that the network's output has a probability interpretation. The problem is, since you have only 1 output, it would either will never train (since the output will 
 always be the same)  or get unreasonable gradients trying to do so.

e.g. Fix

```
model.add(Dense(input_dim=84, activation='sigmoid',
            bias_initializer='normal', units=6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply Log(0) and see what is the result. it is undefined "NAN"
I answered this question in details here 
[NAN in neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472499/issue-nan-with-adam-solver/40473079#40473079)